# Send Link from any website via Firefox does not work anymore

Tags: firefox, browser

I don't remember when it stopped working, but a while back I could right click on any page, anywhere and I'd have the option to "send link..." which then would redirect me to googlemail (which is set as the standard mailing application in firefox) and copy / pasted the link into the mail ready to be sent.

I don't have that option anymore. How can I re-enable it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firefox 17.0.1 there's an **Email Link...** option on my **File** menu which does what you said.

Comment: Any way to move it to the right-click context menu? I'm absolutely sure I had it in the context menu before.

Comment: @DonSalva: When right-clicking on what?

Comment: @DonSalva: I have a bookmarklet that also does this via JavaScript, It's would be possible to it into a Toolbar icon, which would make it accessible with one normal click. I've never seen what you describe on the right-click context menu. Perhaps you used to have some add-on that was providing it...

Comment: This option was removed in Firefox 16. Here is the relevant bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=239307

Comment: As I said I have a bookmarklet attached to a TooLBar button that does this, so have never used the menu or right-click built-in version -- generally wouldn't have noticed their coming or going. I also have another similar one which will quotes any text selected on the webpage into the email message it creates.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/send-link-in-context-menu/) is an extension that was created to replace that very functionality (which was removed in Firefox 16 in [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=239307) bug).